# Authenticating Google account in python script

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, authentication, python-requests

I have a java Google App Engine restful server implemented via Jersey. I am able to make successful GET, POST, PUT, and DELETEs using Postman, a browser based curl like program, when signed into my Google account  in the browser session.

Now I am trying to make similar calls in a Python script using the Requests library.

```
payload = "{\"key\":1, \"dateOpened\":2341342, \"dateClosed\":0, \"description\":\"test\", \"urgency\":2, \"staus\":1}"
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/ticket", params=payload)
print r.status_code
```

When I do this I get a redirect which I am unsure how to handle.

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.AppEngineAuthentication$AppEngineAuthenticator authenticate
Got /ticket but no one was logged in, redirecting.
```

How am I able to make it log in as well using the Requests library? I would like to continue using the Requests library if possible due to its simplicity, but I am a new to using it.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get that "redirect"? Where does that information come from?

Comment: It comes from the console after running the maven project.

Comment: The security constraint in the web.xml. Redirect to Google log in screen if they are not logged in.